# unable to figure out what's wrong with the formula

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var johnHeight = prompt('Enter the height');

var johnAge =prompt('Enter the age');

var ranaHeight = prompt('Enter the height');

var ranaAge =prompt('Enter the age');   

var johnScore = johnHeight + 5 * johnAge;

var win = document.getElementById('winner');

if (johnScore > ranaScore) {

        win.innerHTML = 'John is the winner with ' + johnScore + ' points';

}

else if (johnScore < ranaScore) {

    win.innerHTML = 'Rana is the winner with ' + ranaScore + ' points';
}

else if (johnScore == ranaScore) {

    win.innerHTML = 'It\'s a draw';
}
```

When I try to run the code, everything works fine but the formula i.e JohnScore or ranaScore doesn't calculate correct values.
when I remove the prompt and give those variables a predefined values, it works fine..
can someone solve please.

Comment: Looks like `ranaScore` is undefined - the score was never calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a variable set up for ranaScore, and for the johnScore variable if you mean to add 5 to his height and then multiply by age which means it needs to be:

```
var johnScore = (johnHeight + 5) * johnAge;
```

if that's not what you need you may try:

```
var johnScore = johnHeight + (5 * johnAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value from prompt is coming as string. So to get the right calculation you need to convert that to number. Notice `+` before prompt.
Also you need to define `ranaScore`.

So if johnHeight is "10" and johnAge is "5", let's look how this was being evaluated by javascript:

```
var johnScore = johnHeight + 5 * johnAge;

johnScore = "10" + 5* "5" which is "10" + "25" which is "1025".
```

```js
var johnHeight = +prompt('Enter the height');

var johnAge = +prompt('Enter the age');

var ranaHeight = +prompt('Enter the height');

var ranaAge = +prompt('Enter the age');

var johnScore = johnHeight + 5 * johnAge;
var ranaScore = ranaHeight + 5 * ranaAge;
var win = document.getElementById('winner');

if (johnScore > ranaScore) {

  win.innerHTML = 'John is the winner with ' + johnScore + ' points';

} else if (johnScore < ranaScore) {

  win.innerHTML = 'Rana is the winner with ' + ranaScore + ' points';
} else if (johnScore == ranaScore) {

  win.innerHTML = 'It\'s a draw';
}
```

```html
<div id="winner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful.

Comment: @siddharthagantedi Please accept the solution since it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your variable ranaScore has not been defined, so you need this line.

```
            var ranaScore = rannaHeight + 5 * rannaAge;
```

Although in real life scenario you will need to build your JS function to receives arguments instead of using static variables e.g  see very basic example below.

```
            function comparevalues(arg1,arg2){
                if (arg1 > arg2) {
                    win.innerHTML = arg1 + 'is greater than ' + arg2; //arg 1 wins
                }
                else if (arg1 < arg2) {
                    win.innerHTML = arg2 + 'is greater '  + arg1; //arg 2 wins
                }
                else {
                    win.innerHTML = arg2 + 'is equal to '  + arg1; //draw
                }
            }
            comparevalues(4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always prompt returns string type , convert it into number using ParseInt method.
var  johnHeight=parseInt(prompt('Enter the height'));